# Unable to read the parameter value inside a class using TestNG

Tags: testng, cucumber, junit

To achieve parallel execution, I am updating my existing Junit project to TestNG. 
The requirement here is to run one scenario in different browsers using TestNG

```
RunnerClass is as follows:

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        format   = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json","rerun:target/rerun_featureName.txt"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/com.philips.rs.testcases.sanity.ui.features/02_adUserLogin.feature"},                               
        strict = true,
        monochrome = true,
        glue = {"com.philips.rs.ui.stepdefs","com.philips.rs.backend.stepdefs","com.philips.rs.utils"},
        tags = {"@rsUITest","@sanity",}

        )

@Test
public class PBPRunnerSanityUITest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

The class where browser parameter is fetched.

```
public class WebDriverFactory {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static String currentBrowser = null;
    final static int TIMEOUT1 = 30;
    final static int TIMEOUT2 = 90;
    final static int TIMEOUT3 = 120;

    @Parameters("browser")
    @BeforeTest
    public static WebDriver createDriver(String browser) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException, IOException {

        currentBrowser = browser;
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities() ;

        switch (browser) {

        case "IE_LOCAL":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","./driver_exe/IEDriverServer.exe");
            capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
            break;
        case "IE_REMOTE":

            break;
        case "CHROME_LOCAL":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./driver_exe/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            break;
        case "FIREFOX_LOCAL":       
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./driver_exe/geckodriver.exe");   
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 1);
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
            profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf,image/png,image/gif,application/json;charset=UTF-8,application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8,application/font-woff,text/csv");
            profile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", true );
            capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
            capabilities.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
            break;
        case "CHROME_REMOTE":
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start .\\batchFiles\\seleniumServer.bat");
            String nodeURL = "130.147.173.151:4444/wb/hub";
            capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
            capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
            driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), capabilities);         

        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return driver;
    }


    public WebDriver getDriver()
    {
        return driver;
    }


}
```

TestNG XML file looks as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">

  <test name ="FirefoxTest">
  <parameter name= "browser" value ="firefox"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.philips.rs.application.setup.PBPRunnerSanityUITest"/>
    </classes>   
  </test> 

    <test name ="IETest">
  <parameter name= "browser" value ="ie"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.philips.rs.application.setup.PBPRunnerSanityUITest"/>
    </classes>  
  </test>

</suite>
```

I am not able to able to fetch parameter value "Browser" in webDriverFactory Class, when Test is ran, code is not reached till WebDriverFactory . 
Please let me where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, there is no reference to `WebDriverFactory` anywhere, therefore its code is ignored.

You could try modifying PBPRunnerSanityUITest.java like this:

```
@Test
public class PBPRunnerSanityUITest extends WebDriverFactory {

}
```

And then update WebDriverFactory.java like this:

```
public class WebDriverFactory extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with same code provided, executed fine for me with out any exceptions. How did you create the testng.xml file? If written manually, try the below instead:

1. <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on src (or required package) in Eclipse
2. Move to TestNG
3. Select Convert to TestNG
4. Click on Finish (you can provide names for suite and test here)

Open the created testng.xml file, using `parallel="false"`

Now run the testng.xml file. Also, try to avoid naming conventions with reserved words like DataProvider, TestNG etc.